# Can I publish articles that are written by a writer who is 17?

Tags: united-states, employment, minor

I have a news site running ads and I need to know if I can publish articles from a volunteer writer who is 17. This pertains to United States law.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so long as the minor can and does give you permission to use their intellectual property that way – [and it appears they can](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/14468/10).